# Intellij / webstorm pointing to one project

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

I have a Play project. I use Intellij for the Java portion, but like to use Webstorm for the javascript part.

How can I do this ? Obviously right now, they keep overwriting the config file... :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using WebStorm and IntelliJ at the same time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26479142/using-webstorm-and-intellij-at-the-same-time)

Comment: The answers are outdated. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/26479142/136247 for a real solution.

Answer (score 2):

IntelliJ is perfectly capable of dealing nicely with JavaScript.  Why do you need WebStorm?  I'd recommend that you manage both the Java and web parts of your application in IntelliJ.  I believe Play support is available, too:

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/play!.html

Answer (score 2):

IntelliJ IDEA contains all the WebStorm features, these products are not designed to be used together, on the same machine and on the same project at the same time.