# Using WebStorm and IntelliJ at the same time

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

I have code for an existing web application built with java, jsp, and js.

I would like to use WebStorm for the JS part of the development and the free edition of IntelliJ for the rest of the code, but it doesn't look like I can open the same project in both as they seem to step on each other.

Is there a way I can do this without having to close/switch the IDEs all the time?

Comment: Yes -- you cannot open the SAME project twice. Make 2 separate projects: one for JS  part (WebStorm) and another for Java/JSP

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Opening Idea project in WebStorm and vice versa is not a recommended approach. Different Idea-based IDEs (RubyMine, PHPStorm, WebStorm, PyCharm, IDEA) have the same project format (.idea) but different settings/module types that aren't compatible. So we strongly recommend to avoid sharing the same project between IDEs.
If you like to work on the same front-end sources in different IDEs, I'd suggest sharing the sources folder(s) but keeping the .idea folders separated: just create a new empty project in WebStorm and add your sources root as additional content root in Settings/Directories

Comment: This actually works surprisingly well. I favour creating a JetBrains directory, create a folder for each project you have that needs to use two JetBrains IDEs, then add the content root and it works fine.

Comment: This did work, what about GIT though?
I created a GIT repository inside the JetBrains directory (that you created as an example), but I could not *add* the files that are in the external "content root". Can this be done somehow? (so that I can have a separate GIT for this?)